# android. Activity не видит id кнопки

Tags: android, kotlin

не подскажите почему из моего activity не видна кнопка, для которой я хочу задать функцию, срабатывающую при нажатии.
[image: layout]

[image: activity]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А его и не должно быть видно. Скорей всего вы пытаетесь использовать kotlin synthetic, но не добавили соответствующего импорта. Но про kotlin synthetic лучше забыть, так как он теперь deprecated. Используйте `findViewById` или [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)